# should I move related columns in a new table?

Tags: database, database-design

I have a customer table that references an address - a 1 to 1 relationship, with several fields. No other table currently references an address. Does it therefore make more sense to store all the fields under one table, even though it can be encapsulated or should I just create a separate address table to store the address fields. What are the advantages/disadvantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it depends on your requirements.

If some of the field values can be updated, but the entity should stay the same (should be referenced by same key), then you need a separate table for it. For example, it’s required to maintain a database of valid addresses, and customer should select a predefined address from a list instead of typing it by hand, or it’s required to provide some specific behavior based on address location and so on.

In your case doing so just adds absolutely unnecessary bit of complexity to the model.

Having single table and using OOP language you can still encapsulate customer address in separate object (so called [Value Object](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html) pattern).